# Postgres and oracle in one project

Tags: spring, postgresql, oracle, mybatis

In my project, I should receive data from the oracle and after processing it, write it to postgres, in my case, I need to use mybatis to communicate with the database. Can I connect to different databases in one project?(Postgres, Oracle) Have you faced such a situation?

If so, how do configure the datasourse? I need advice, thanks in advance. It will be great to see code examples

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы You just need to create two sets of `DataSource` and `SqlSessionFactoryBean`. See this [demo](https://github.com/kazuki43zoo/mybatis-spring-boot-multi-ds-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/MybatisDemoApplication.java) which uses [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).